# AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer could not be instantiated

Tags: websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud, buildpack

I am deploying a Java EE app to Bluemix, and when first request arrives I got this error:

> 2015-05-20T23:11:58.51+0200 [App/0]      OUT [INFO    ] FFDC1015I: An
>   FFDC Incident has been created: "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider
>   org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer
>   could not be instantiated
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost startWebApp" at
>   ffdc_15.05.20_21.11.58.0.log

It is a piece of code from Liberty Buildpack I think. 
Here it is the content file ffdc_15.05.20_21.11.58.0.log (it seems a ClassNotFoundException but as it is not part of my app I don't know what to do):

> Exception = java.util.ServiceConfigurationError Source =
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost probeid = startWebApp
>   Stack Dump = java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider
>   org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer
>   could not be instantiated     at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2454)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:1038)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6396)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:446)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:248)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:313)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:306)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:449)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:254)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:297)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:241)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:390)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:362)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.spring.AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer.(AutoReconfigurationServletContainerInitializer.java:33)
>     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   ... 23 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:246)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findOrDelegateLoadClass(AppClassLoader.java:390)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:362)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  ... 35 more

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your application is using Spring Framework, and this triggers the [Spring Auto-Reconfiguration](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ibm-websphere-liberty-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-spring-auto-reconfiguration.md). If you don't need this auto-reconfiguration support, you can disable it by setting the below environment variable for your application and do a restage:

```
cf set-env <app-name> JBP_CONFIG_SPRINGAUTORECONFIGURATION "enabled: false"

cf restage <app-name>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was told that the issue happens because I have an old version of Spring in the app. I think this should be documented somewhere... but it is clear now.